# Best way to connect nearest points in graph

Tags: java, nodes

I have array of points (cities) and I'm searching for the best way how to find 10 nearest points and connect them to create graph. It has to be exactly 10 coneection from each points.

Point class:

```
public class City 
{
    int key;
    public int population;
    Point position;

    City(int key, int population, Point position)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.population = population;
        this.position = position;
    }

    void setPopulation(int newPopulation)
    {
        this.population = newPopulation;
    }
}
```

Now I have all points in one array:

```
City[] cities = new City[3000];
```

All points have coordinates (all coordinates are mutliples of five, because I have to be sure, that each point have nearest point further than 5 (km).

And all cities was generated randomly, so first city can be in left upper corner and second city in array can be in right bottom corner.

That's how look all points, when I draw them.
[image: map]

Now I need advice, how can I find the nearest points and how can I connect them to create graph.

Any advice? Thanks for all reply.

Comment: I think you need more constraints. In 1D this is trivial, but in 2D this is hard. Take two points x and y. Y might be in x's 10 closest points, but x might not be in y's 10 closest points. So do they have to be the 10 closest? or can it be between 10-20 connections per point?

Comment: If the connections are bidirectional(seems so), you gonna need a pivot city to determine 10 nearest point and you need to mark B is connected with A, if you connect A with B.

Comment: They have to be connected with 10 closest. When X will be connect to Y, then Y have to be connect to X. I need to create valued undirected graph.

Comment: @Sk1X1 Y might be among 10 closest of X but it may not apply vice-versa. So, you need a pivot city. If you change your pivot, your graph MAY change.

Comment: Making the graph undirected, having all points connect to the 10 closest points and disallowing any other edges isn't always possible. Imagine for instance a cluster of 11 points very close together. They will obviously connect to each other. Now, add another point 1000 km away. It's impossible to connect it without either allowing more than 10 connections, making the edges directed or allowing some connections to not be to the 10 closest points.

Comment: When I have all points randomly generated, I'm pretty sure I wont have one city too far to connect them. Example: I pick up first city in array, which is placed for example in left upper corner, and connect him to nearest 10 points (and immediately connect that 10 points to this point), then I pick up second city, which is placed in right bottom corner, and connect him to nearest 10 points (and immediately connect that 10 points to this point) etc, then it's very small possibility that I wont have any city connected.

Comment: @Smallhacker I think an easier example would be to simplify the problem. Instead of wanting the closest 10 connections, look for the closest 2 connections. Now this is obviously not always possible for every point to end up with exactly 2 connection. If what you want is for the sum of all connections to be lowest, then we've got an NP-Complete problem on our hands(reduction to TSP is pretty trivial here).

Answer (score 0):

A relatively quick solution would be to use an adapted Breadth First Search on each point and make connections to the first 10 points it encounters.

Answer (score 0):

a very easy way is to use a library for that, e.g. [JSI](http://jsi.sourceforge.net/) (see [nearestN](http://jsi.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/infomatiq/jsi/rtree/RTree.html#nearestN%28com.infomatiq.jsi.Point,%20gnu.trove.TIntProcedure,%20int,%20float%29)) and you can be sure that its fast (actually, jsi is an [RTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)-implementation optimized for spatial queries.

Comment: This is fine when you have 1 point and want the 10 closest to it. But as soon as you do this for all points, some points will likely have more than 10 connections.